# Please update includepath error at #include <string_view>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++17, string-view

I have the following configuration in `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed",
                    "C:/MinGW/include/*",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            },
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

My C++ code is:

```cpp
#include <string_view>

using namespace::std;
```

However, I get *"There is #include error. Please update `includePath`"*. But I don't know how can I update it.

---

I am running this on VS Code.
GCC Version - `6.3.0`
C++ Standard - `c++17`
Project structure:

[image]

Comment: `std::string_view` was added in GCC 7. You seem to be using version 6.3, which is too old.

Comment: But others said c++17 has string_view, but why can't I use it...? (Thank you for your comment! I'll add my gcc version)

Comment: Yes it's added in the C++17 standard. But GCC 6.3 (which you seem to use) does not fully support C++17. You need to use at least GCC 7.0. And remember that GCC is up to version 11 now.

Comment: Really thank you... I use MinGW for gcc installation, and I updated MinGW, but its gcc version is still 6.3.0. Version 6.3.0 is the latest version that MinGW can support?

Comment: @hyeminju you can use msys2 or mingw-w64 -- PS: `using namespace::std;` should be `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Last time I installed Linux from scratch it took me just one and a half hours. And I got a fully configured, latest version of gcc, supporting the current C++ standard, right out of the box. It might be easier for you to simply install Linux if you wish to use C++ on Windows. How much time did you already spend on this? More than a couple of hours? It would've taken less time to intall Linux.

Comment: Oh thank you.. Then I'll start this project by WSL(window linux) ;-)! Thank you for your comment Sam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This is for conclusion for this error! *

1. Only GCC 7+ version can use <string_view>
2. https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Multilib%20Toolchains%28Targetting%20Win32%20and%20Win64%29/ray_linn/gcc-9.x-with-ada/ does not support 7+ version gcc.
3. However, if you search "MinGW gcc 9 version", you can find upgraded version mingw.
4. After replace it with the old version mingw, you can use it.

Really thank you for your comments! :-)